# Calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\{\tan x\}}{\tan x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Here is my work but my answer is wrong
\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\{\tan x\}}{\tan x} dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\tan x - [\tan x]}{\tan x} dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\tan x}{\tan x} - \frac{[\tan x]}{\tan x} dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty 1 - \frac{[\tan x]}{\tan x} dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty 1 dx - \int_0^\infty \frac{[\tan x]}{\tan x} dx \\
&= \infty - \left[ \log |x| \right]_0^\infty \\
&= \boxed{\infty}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Where do the final two equalities come from?

Comment: $$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \[tanx]/tanx \, dx \text{ is not convergent. This is because the integrand is undefined at } x = 2\pi, \text{ where } \tan(x) \text{ is undefined. In fact, the integrand is undefined at any odd multiple of } 2\pi.
$$

Comment: Please help someone

Comment: Maybe you want to try the area on $[0,\frac\pi2]$ as looking at the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=frac%28tan%28x%29%29%2Ftan%28x%29), the integral over $[0,\infty)$ diverges

Comment: You certainly can't integrate this function from $0\to\infty$ as you already know that that function is undefined at infinitely many points

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Maybe not with Riemann integration but with Lebesgue integration it wouldn't matter much as long as it's undefined on a set of measure zero.

Comment: wolfram alpha concludes that even the integral from 0 to pi doesnt converge, which means that your full integral diverges as well since the graph is just a copy-paste of what happens between 0 and pi

Comment: It's horrible so I'd be pretty confident saying it diverges, but give up all hope of finding a closed form for this function too

Comment: @KalpeshDesai The [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%5Bfrac%28tan%28x%29%29%2Ftan%28x%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cπ%7D%5D) over $[0,\pi]$ shows the graph is bounded, so the integral should converge

Comment: @ТymaGaidash the frac function that you used in the link is different than the actual **fractional part function** which is defined as $x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor$....just put frac(-1.3) in wa...does it gives the expected result?

Comment: Possible Representation,
$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln\left(\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{j+1}{j}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{j^{2}+1}{\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1}}\right)^{j}\right)$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash it's not bounded, wolfram just stops drawing when there's a vertical asymptote

Comment: @BlackEmperor  Any explanation?

Comment: @KalpeshDesai Oh my bad. I tried evaluating it from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$,
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\operatorname{floor}\left(\tan x\right)}{\tan x}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)}{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\ dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j\left(\ln\left(j+1\right)-\ln\left(j\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(j^{2}+1\right)\right)$$

Comment: Not sure but,
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\{ \tan x \}}{\tan x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}\right)}$$

Comment: @BlackEmperor   But we need to evaluate from  0 to infinity