# Integral $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{ \{ \tan x \} }{\tan x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Motivated by [Calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\{\tan x\}}{\tan x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764059/calculate-int-0-infty-frac-tan-x-tan-xdx)

I want to evaluate the following integral,
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{  \{ \tan x \} }{\tan x}dx$$

Here is the value from Wolfram,
$$I=0.919900494885649087058609882333342085980315192991199436742670023056103944536683559170770204$$

First step would be to write,
$$\{ \tan x \} =\tan x-\lfloor\tan x\rfloor$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\lfloor\tan x\rfloor}{\tan x}dx$$
$$x\to \pi/2-x$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\lfloor\cot x\rfloor}{\cot x}dx$$
$$x\to \cot x$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)}{x\csc^{2}\left(\operatorname{arccot}x\right)}dx$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)}{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)}dx$$
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j\left(\int_{j}^{1+j}\frac{1}{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)}dx\right)$$
Also,
$$\int_{j}^{1+j}\frac{1}{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)}dx=\ln\left(\frac{1+j}{j}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1}{j^{2}+1}\right)$$
or,
$$=\ln\left(\frac{1+j}{j}\left(\frac{j^{2}+1}{\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$
Therefore,
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}j\ln\left(\frac{1+j}{j}\left(\frac{j^{2}+1}{\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$
or,
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln\left(\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+j}{j}\right)^{j}\left(\frac{j^{2}+1}{\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{j}{2}}\right)$$

Note that,
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1+j}{j}\right)^{j}=\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}}{n!}$$
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(\frac{j^{2}+1}{\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{j}{2}}=\frac{1}{\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{1+j^{2}}$$

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+j}{j}\right)^{j}\left(\frac{j^{2}+1}{\left(j+1\right)^{2}+1}\right)^{\frac{j}{2}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}}{n!}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{1+j^{2}}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}}{\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\right)\cdot\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{1+j^{2}}}{n!}\right)$$

Although I am not aware of the proof but it seems that,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{1+j^{2}}}{n!}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}}$$
whereas,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}}{\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\right)=1$$

This would imply,
$$\boxed{I=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}\right)}$$

But this does not work numerically.

Although I have not done this rigorously, I can't seem to find where the mistake is.

Comment: I think it's just numerical error. I evaluated the first integral using MATLAB and got $0.919873097762985$, and the analytical solution was $0.919873127493040$.

Comment: Using Mathematica, there are a lot of numerical issues.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: The problem appears in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**, page $32$, but it is stated with cot. It is the problem **11924** in The American Mathematical Monthly, where it appears with tan (of course, the same author).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is fine and my numerical simulations confirm it up to 3 decimal digits. It is also correct that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{1+j^{2}}}{n!}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^\infty \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{j^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}},
$$
or similarly
$$
\prod_{j=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{j^2}\right)=\frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}.
$$
In the following, we will prove the latter result to conclude your solution.

Denote $A=\prod_{j=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{j^2}\right)$. Therefore,
$$\ln A{=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{j^2}\right)
\\=
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{nj^{2n}}
\\=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\zeta(2n).
}
$$
Now, by replacing [$\zeta(2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2\pi)^{2n}B_{2n}}{2(2n)!}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Bernoulli_numbers_and_the_Riemann_zeta_function), where $B_n$ is the [Bernoulli number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html), we obtain
$$
\ln A
{=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}B_{2n}}{2n(2n)!}
\\=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}B_{2n}\left[1+(-1)^{2n}\right]}{4n(2n)!}
\\=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{n}B_{n}\left[1+(-1)^{n}\right]}{2n(n)!}
\\=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{n}B_{n}}{2n(n)!}
+
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2\pi)^{n}B_{n}}{2n(n)!}.
}
$$
The [characteristics function of Bernoulli numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) is given by
$$
\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_nx^n}{n!},
$$
from which, the following deductions are made:
$$
\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_nx^n}{n!}
{\implies
\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_nx^{n-1}}{n!}
\\\implies
\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_nx^{n-1}}{n!}
\\\overset{\int}{\implies}
\ln\left|\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_nx^n}{n\cdot n!}.
}
$$
Therefore
$$
{
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_n(2\pi)^n}{n\cdot n!}=\ln\left|\frac{e^{-2\pi}-1}{2\pi}\right|
\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_n(-2\pi)^n}{n\cdot n!}=\ln\left|\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi}\right|,
}
$$
and we finally arrive at
$$
\ln A{=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{n}B_{n}}{2n(n)!}
+
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2\pi)^{n}B_{n}}{2n(n)!}
\\=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{e^{-2\pi}-1}{2\pi}\right|+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi}\right|
\\=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{2-e^{-2\pi}-e^{2\pi}}{4\pi^2}\right|
\\=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{2-2\cosh 2\pi}{4\pi^2}\right|
\\=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{4\sinh^2\pi}{4\pi^2}\right|
\\=\ln \frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}.
}
$$
Therefore, $A=\prod_{j=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{j^2}\right)=\frac{\sinh\pi}{\pi}$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for the proof!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

$$P_n=\frac 1{n!}{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{1+j^{2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sinh (\pi ) \,\Gamma (n+(1-i))\, \Gamma (n+(1+i))}{\pi \,
   \Gamma (n+1)^2}}$$
$$P_n=\sqrt{\frac{\sinh (\pi )}\pi}\left( 1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{3}{8 n^2}-\frac{7}{48 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

$$Q_n=\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{n}}{\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\,P_n$$
$$Q_n==\sqrt{\frac{\sinh (\pi )}\pi}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{7}{4 n^2}-\frac{8}{3 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$
The relative error is smaller than $0.01$% when $n \geq 14$.

**Edit**

It is regrettable that Wolfram Alpha does not report troubles durin numerical integration.

Enter

`NIntegrate[Cot[x]*FractionalPart[Tan[x]],{x,0,Pi/2},WorkingPrecision->20]`

and play with the last number.

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{result} \\
 20 & 0.9199695568 \\
 30 & 0.9199868334 \\
 40 & 0.9194955880 \\
 50 & 0.9198846296 \\
 60 & 0.9198639873 \\
 70 & 0.9198721786 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the last one the error estimate is $0.000174$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I guess it is a bit hard to evaluate it numerically.

Comment: @BlackEmperor. Not hard but very, very hard. Why don't you use Wolfram Cloud ? Just register, it is free and you have all Mathematica.

Comment: Yes I have registered for Wolfram Cloud, and that is how I gave the evaluation at the beginning of my question. It's just that I was confused because only 3 digits were matching.

Comment: @BlackEmperor. Didn't you see a bunch of warning messages ? This is very nice problem.

Comment: Yeah I kind of ignored them. As I am still new to it, but I used "WorkingPrecision" and "AccuracyGoal" and cranked them upto 80. Also the problem is kind of from the linked post.